# Problem creating Custom Control based on ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm a newcomer to WPF, trying to make use of Custom Controls. I'm having trouble with making a custom ListView class.

Here is the xaml code from `Generic.xaml`:

```xml
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyListView}" BasedOn = "{StaticResource {x:Type ListView}}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    </Style>
```

And the class declaration from `MyListView.cs`:

```cs
namespace MyProject
{
    public class MyListView : ListView
    {
        static MyListView()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyListView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyListView)));
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error message:

```
Exception: Cannot find resource named 'System.Windows.Controls.ListView'. Resource names are case sensitive.
```

Can anyone point out what's going on here and what I'm doing wrong?

Perhaps worth noting that I *have* successfully added a custom button class using the same approach, and it works fine. The code for that is as follows:

```xml
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:LargeButton}" BasedOn = "{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
```

```cs
namespace MyProject
{
    public class LargeButton : Button
    {
        static LargeButton()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(LargeButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(LargeButton)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, are you sure you want to create a custom ListView, and not a custom ListBox? The former would only be needed when you set its View property.

Comment: Besides that, it should work without BasedOn. Try `<Style TargetType="local:MyListView">...</Style>`.